# need to create the api for category and subcategory (- using reverse relationship )

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am creating a api which should called the category with its respective subCategory
Like this

```
category 
     {
      name,
      subCategory[
          {
              name
          },
          {
              name
          }
      ]
     },...
```

here is my category model

```
const categorySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name:{
    type:String,
    unique : true,
    required : true
  }
});
```

and here is my subCategory Model

```
const subCategorySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  category:{
    type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref : 'Category',
    require : true
  },
  name:{
    type:String,
    unique:true,
    required:true
  }
});
```

Comment: What is your question? You haven't asked anything.

Comment: I want to get the result as category with list sub categories